# How to enable "Search for text when I start typing" in Google Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

One of my favorite features of Mozilla Firefox is the "Search for text when I start typing" feature found in the "Advanced" options.  Is there an extension out there that will add this feature or another way of adding it to Google Chrome?

Comment: In addition to hitting F3 to start it you mean?

Comment: Exactly, in FF as long as focus is not in a text box or something when I start typing it starts searching on the page, a feature I'm missing quite a bit in Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [Type-ahead-find extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/cpecbmjeidppdiampimghndkikcmoadk)

> - Start writing (or press /) to start text search.
> - Press ' to search only links.

Installed and tested, feels just like you've turned on the option in Firefox.